# Experimental Implications of Wigner Distribution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, experimental-physics, quantum-entanglement, epr-experiment

I'm interested in the experimental implications of the Wigner quasiprobability distribution in quantum physics, but haven't been able to find anything that addresses my particular question.

Specifically, suppose one were to carry out the original EPR experiment on a sequence of $n$ entangled particles, with Alice measuring the successive positions, $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, and Bob measuring the successive momenta, $p_1, \ldots, p_n$.  As I understand things, if Alice and Bob separately were to construct histograms of their respective observations, Alice would see a pattern similar to the marginal probability density function of "position", whereas Bob would see a pattern similar to the marginal probability density function of "momentum".

However, when Alice and Bob get together to compare their results, what would the empirical joint probability distribution (of the pairs, $[x_1,p_1], \ldots, [x_n,p_n]$) look like?

Please feel free to tell me if this question is poorly posed.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the connection with the Wigner. Quasiprobability distributions are a way to represent quantum states, why would the existence of such representations affect experimental observations?

Comment: @gIS  I'm assuming the theoretical joint distribution of "position" (measured by Alice) and "momentum" (measured by Bob) is described by a quasiprobability distribution function (i.e., with some negative values in its sample space).  However, the empirical (experimental) joint distribution of the two quantities -- which presumably can be found when Alice and Bob compare notes -- would have to be a proper probability distribution for all *n*.  My question is:  What proper joint distribution does the empirical joint distribution approach as *n* --> infinity?  Or does it diverge by oscillation?

Comment: it sounds like you misunderstand what quasiprobability distributions are about. Probabilistic and "quasiprobabilistic" descriptions agree on any prediction, so there is no difference in using one or the other as far as predicting measurements goes. You get back the probability distribution corresponding to measurements by taking the marginals of the quasiprobability one.

Comment: @gIS  I agree; I probably am misunderstanding something.  To isolate the problem, perhaps I could break my thoughts into simpler pieces.  (1) Is it reasonable to assume Alice and Bob each will record a set of random measurements converging to some proper marginal density function, f_A(x) and f_B(p), respectively?  (2) Is it reasonable to assume that, when Alice and Bob compare notes, they'll find that the paired observations, [x_i, p_i], converge to some proper joint density function, g(x, p)?  (3) Assuming f_A(x), f_B(p), and g(x, p) exist, how are they functionally related?  Thank you.

Comment: for starters, the quasiprob distrib description would assign a function $f(x,p)$ to *each* of $A$ and $B$. Sure, you obtain a joint probability distribution over $x$ of $A$ and $p$ of $B$, let's call it $P(x,p)$ but this in principle has no relation with what would have been the quasidistributions of $A$ or $B$. You also don't get the commutator comparing notes, you only get the joint probability distribution. Moreover, if $A$ measures $x$, then $B$'s measurement of $p$ will probably be fully uncorrelated (assuming the states were initially correlated in position), so $P(x_A,p_B)=P_A(x)P_B(p)$

Comment: @gIS  Thank you for answering my questions, and for providing some very useful notation.  Could you explain further:  (1) why (,) is not identical to (,-)? and (2) why (,) is not identical to (,)?

Comment: how is that related to the question at hand?

Comment: @gIS  I'm trying to work through my misconceptions in order to revise the original question.  I would have thought (i) (,) = (,-) and (ii) (,) = (,).  The rationale for (i) is that EPR argue that, for fixed x, if A measures p, then B must measure -p.  The rationale for (ii) is that the empirical (experimental) distribution of [x, p] should converge to the theoretical distribution.  Thank you.

Comment: where are you reading this from? I'd recommend some introductory material on quasiprobability distributions and Wigner functions. The Wigner $f(x,p)$ characterizes a *single* state, while here you have two systems. You cannot compare $f(x,p)$ with the joint probability distribution of the full system, they are completely different quantities referring to completely different things. Also, it doesn't make much sense to talk of the "experimentla distribution" of $[x,p]=i$.

Comment: @gIS My original question came from trying to understand EPR (1935) in terms of prob. theory. I read L. Cohen (1966, 1988), as well as others in that literature. As noted before, I'm sure I have misconceptions about the Wigner distribution; but I'd like to take things one step at a time. Am I correct that the EPR experiment is replicable, so for any number of trials n, A and B could compare notes? If that's the case, why couldn't they construct an empirical (experimental) joint density function, (,), for each n, and then study the asymptotic behavior of that empirical distribution?

Comment: unfortunately, comments are not the place to get this sort of clarifications. You should ask separate questions focusing on the individual misconceptions